# Capture JavaScript alert text using BeautifulSoup

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup

I am using this JavaScript to validate a form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function validateForm()
        {
            var a=document.forms["orderform"]["Name"].value;
            var b=document.forms["orderform"]["Street"].value;
            var c=document.forms["orderform"]["ZIP"].value;
            var d=document.forms["orderform"]["City"].value;
            var e=document.forms["orderform"]["PhoneNumber"].value;
            if (
                a==null || a=="" || 
                b==null || b=="" || 
                c==null || c=="" || 
                d==null || d=="" || 
                e==null || e==""
                )
            {alert("Please fill all the required fields.");
            return false;
            }
        }
      </script>
```

I am trying to capture the alert text using BeatifulSoup:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("index.html") as fp:
  soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, "lxml")

for script in soup.find_all(re.compile("(?<=alert\(\").+(?=\")")):
  print(script)
```

This does not return anything. This is based on the example given in the BS documentation under 'A regular expression' to find tag names starting with a 'b':

```
import re
for tag in soup.find_all(re.compile("^b")):
    print(tag.name)
# body
# b
```

but I seem to be unable to find the equivalent to 'print(tag.name)' that would print the alert text. Or am I completely on the wrong track? Any help is much appreciated.

Edit:
I tried:

```
pattern = re.compile("(?<=alert\(\").+(?=\")"))
for script in soup.find_all ('script'):
  print(script.pattern)
```

This returns "None".

Comment: What do you mean tag that starts with B?

Comment: The example in the documentation matches the letter 'b' at the beginning of a line (^b) and thus returns the tag names "body" and "b". I was hoping to tweak this example for my purposes, but to no avail for now.

Comment: The escape before the parenthesis in `"(?<=alert\(\").+(?=\")"` has no effect.  Maybe use an `r"..."` string.

Comment: Btw, the commas in `a==null || a=="", b==null || b=="", a==null || c=="", c==null || d=="", d==null || e=="", a==null || e==""` mean that this whole test is equivalent to `a==null || e==""`.  Comma is very different from `||` in JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Comment: @MikeSamuel Thanks for looking at this JavaScript. Looks like I completely messed it up, not only for the commas. I fixed it in the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running over the all `html` data will not work. First you need to extract the `script` data then you can easily parse the `alert` text.

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("index.html") as fp:
  soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, "lxml")

script = soup.find("script").extract()

# find all alert text
alert = re.findall(r'(?<=alert\(\").+(?=\")', script.text)
print(alert)
```

Output:

```
['Please fill all the required fields.']
```

Comment: This works. Thank you for explaining and for the code. In my case, I am getting '[u'Please fill all the required fields.']', and I'll need to get this Unicode marker and the brackets removed from my output. But I see this is something others have already asked here before, and I'll find out.

Comment: @cbp Glad it help you. For single alert `message` you can try `print(alert[0])`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks again.

Comment: Btw, I am trying to upvote your answer, but the system doesn't let me. Not enough reputation yet...

Comment: @cbp I see. May be some issue with the system. Anyway, you can approve the answer.

Comment: It's because this is my first post, and I haven't acccumulated enough reputation points yet. I will vote it up once I get enough points. I marked the answer as accepted.

Comment: This doesn't work when you have <body> tag and the script is outside the <body> tag @Pankaj

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this may be what you're looking for:

```
html = """
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm()
    {
        var a=document.forms["orderform"]["Name"].value;
        var b=document.forms["orderform"]["Street"].value;
        var c=document.forms["orderform"]["ZIP"].value;
        var d=document.forms["orderform"]["City"].value;
        var e=document.forms["orderform"]["PhoneNumber"].value;
        if (a==null || a=="", b==null || b=="", a==null || c=="", c==null || d=="", d==null || e=="", a==null || e=="")
        {alert("Please fill all the required fields.");
        return false;
        }
    }
  </script>
   """

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
alert = soup.text.split('"')
alert[33]
```

Output:

```
'Please fill all the required fields.'
```