# Scrape alert text from window alert when alert is shown

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am using python requests library and BeautifulSoup.
There is one URL when the requests is not valid it returns HTML with `alert()` pop up.
The problem in Beautifulsoup is I cannot get the `window.alert` pop up text.

I have tried using the regex method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111752/extracting-text-from-script-tag-using-beautifulsoup-in-python) but it doesn't seem to work.

Thus when doing:

```
for script in soup.find_all("script"):
    alert = re.findall(r'(?<=alert\(\").+(?=\")', script.text)
```

The script never gets the executed script.

This is the script that I am extracting:

```html
<script language="JavaScript">
if(top.frames.length != 0) {
    location.href="frame_break.jsp"
}
</script>

<html>
<body>

</body>
</html>


<script>
    var err='User ID';
    alert(err);
    iBankForm.action='login.jsp';
    iBankForm.submit();
  </script>
```

I am expecting to get the alert text which is `User ID`.
I notice if I have  tag that I can't grab the script down below
If I remove  or move the script into the body tag then I can get the

```html
<script>
    var err='User ID';
    alert(err);
    iBankForm.action='login.jsp';
    iBankForm.submit();
  </script>
```

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948405/capture-javascript-alert-text-using-beautifulsoup

Comment: @JoaoPereira this doesn't work cause the html has multiple <script>
so I need to do soup.find_all() instead of soup.find(), in find_all even I loop it, it doesn't find the correct script, because I think the alert is shown to window, so it stops before getting all the alert

Comment: @Fozoro its different, due to nature of the html is written, it is not able to get the alert
I have tried the other answer on my test, it works but not in this html structure

Comment: in that answer, extract() is called for the script found through the usage of the find() method. have you tried calling the extract() function for each script instance inside the loop?

Comment: can you pastebin the html file? Where it is failing.

Comment: @QHarr https://pastebin.com/F0igdfr5

Comment: it's outside of the HTML tags so won't be in soup. Examine the html and see if you can add in a lookaround to isolate the right var

Comment: it is solved by using `html5lib` parser library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is solved by using `html5lib` parser library
If you read the documentation https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ it Parses pages the same way a web browser does
So it will be able to get the script outside body tag

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(payload, 'html5lib')
        errors = None
        for scr in soup.find_all("script"):
            scrExtract = scr.extract()
            alert = re.findall('err="(.*\w)', scrExtract.text)
            if len(alert) > 0:
                errors = alert[0]

        print(errors)
```

Answer (score 1):

When running BeautifulSoup's `diagnose()` over your data I obtain the following info:

```
data = '''
<script language="JavaScript">
if(top.frames.length != 0) {
    location.href="frame_break.jsp"
}
</script>

<html>
<body>

</body>
</html>


<script>
    var err='User ID';
    alert(err);
    iBankForm.action='login.jsp';
    iBankForm.submit();
  </script>'''

from bs4.diagnose import diagnose

diagnose(data)
```

Prints:

```
Diagnostic running on Beautiful Soup 4.7.1
Python version 3.6.8 (default, Jan 14 2019, 11:02:34) 
[GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]]
Found lxml version 4.3.3.0
Found html5lib version 1.0.1

Trying to parse your markup with html.parser
Here's what html.parser did with the markup:
<script language="JavaScript">
 if(top.frames.length != 0) {
    location.href="frame_break.jsp"
}
</script>
<html>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
<script>
 var err='User ID';
    alert(err);
    iBankForm.action='login.jsp';
    iBankForm.submit();
</script>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Trying to parse your markup with html5lib
Here's what html5lib did with the markup:
<html>
 <head>
  <script language="JavaScript">
   if(top.frames.length != 0) {
    location.href="frame_break.jsp"
}
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script>
   var err='User ID';
    alert(err);
    iBankForm.action='login.jsp';
    iBankForm.submit();
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Trying to parse your markup with lxml
Here's what lxml did with the markup:
<html>
 <head>
  <script language="JavaScript">
   if(top.frames.length != 0) {
    location.href="frame_break.jsp"
}
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Trying to parse your markup with lxml-xml
Here's what lxml-xml did with the markup:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<script language="JavaScript">
 if(top.frames.length != 0) {
    location.href="frame_break.jsp"
}
</script>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

From this I can see, the `lxml` parser will not parse the last `<script>` so you never reach it through BeautifulSoup. The solution is different parser, e.g. `html.parser`:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')


for script in soup.select('script:contains(alert)'):
    alert = re.findall(r'(?<=alert\().+(?=\))', script.text)
    print(alert)
```

Prints:

```
['err']
```